# Pandas merge or concat on list of pd.series. along columns. Series indexes may overlap

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, concatenation

I am producing a list of pandas series where the index is temperature and data is some volume of a thermodynamic solid phase present at said temperatures. Each time I run a simulation I don't know how many phases will be returned so I am appending them to a list of pandas series to be concatenated along columns. For Example, lets say I am interested in phases present from 400 to 900 degrees and want to fill a data frame whose index is all the temperatures.

```
# data.values() is an object whose values x's are temperature and y's are amount of some phase.

lst_phases = []
for d in data.values():
    idx = pd.Index(d.temp)
    idx.drop_duplicates(keep='first')
    ## sometimes there can be duplicate temperatures with an empty index in between each.
    ## ex. temp = [473, 478, 480, , 480, 483....]  # so I drop the first, I am not sure what to do abut the empty index or if that is my issue.
    s = pd.Series(d.phase, index=idx, name=d.name)
    lst_phases.append(s)

result = pd.concat(lst_phases, axis=1)
```

returns:

```
ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicat axis
```

I have also tried do a merge like so.

```
pd.merge(lst_phases[0], lst_phases[1], how='outer', left_index='True', right_index='True')
```

This returns a full outer join of so my index of temperatures are all the temperatures in order and exactly what I am trying to achieve. The issue is that it's difficult to do a merge on a list of phases especially when I don't know how many phases/pd.Series I will have for each simulation

Comment: I'm not sure whether I understand exactly what is it you want to do. Is it an option for you to join/concat/merge using the default range index (i.e are there always the same number of rows?) and then sort your dataframe on the 'Temp' column afterwards?

Comment: @Jason, there is not always the same number of rows for each but there is a constant temperature range which I want to be my index. Lets say in one simulation I get 6 phases total (so 6 pd.series). the index could be any length from from temperatures 400-900. Some phase might be all 500 rows. Some phases might be only present between temperatures  600-700, ie 100 rows but those temperatures fall between 400-900 so I should be able to merge on the left and right index as a full outer join. How do I do this for an unknown number of pd.series? pd.concate(how='outer') would be nice.

Comment: Would using a `for` loop over all of your `pd.Series` where you using the `pd.merge` which produced the desired behaviour with current data + each new phase work for you? If the files are all stored in the same directory you can use the `glob` module to get a list of all the files.

Comment: The data is actually coming from another python api where a I have a simulation running in a for loop with the data being a contained in a dictionary. So everytime I run the simulation I could a completely different dictionary.

Comment: What I am thinking of doing is transposing the series to a one row dataframe with x number of columns where the columns are a step in temperature. Before I transpose I can remove duplicates in xy data using set(). I will try this later on when I have time and post it.

Comment: I just realized I need the series name to be the dataframe row index as series.T will return its self...